# Pasar filas a columnas en MYSQL con datos variables

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando sobre una base de datos en MySQL, tengo la siguiente tabla pero necesito coger los datos repetidos de la columna Ubicación y ponerlos como columnas.

```
-------------------------------------------------
Producto |   Marca   |  Ubicación  | Total
   547         X         España       7
   212         Y         Italia       5
   547         X         Italia       2
--------------------------------------------------
```

Y necesito que me salga una tabla como la siguiente

```
----------------------------------------------------
  Producto | Marca | España | Italia | Total
     547       X       7        2        9
     212       Y       0        5        5
----------------------------------------------------
```

Mencionar que tanto los valores de la columna Ubicación como Producto pueden aumentar en el número de datos. Si por ejemplo añadiese la ubicación Alemania, se debería de crear en la segunda tabla una columna con el nombre Alemania.
No se si esto sería posible.

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Comment: Lee sobre tablas pivotantes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza la función `SUM()` y la cláusula `GROUP BY` para agrupar los registros por producto y marca, y luego sumar los valores del total para cada grupo. Con la función `IFNULL()` y la expresión `CASE` muestras ceros en lugar de valores nulos en las columnas España e Italia.

```
SELECT 
  producto, 
  marca,
  IFNULL(SUM(CASE ubicacion WHEN 'España' THEN total END), 0) AS España,  
  IFNULL(SUM(CASE ubicacion WHEN 'Italia' THEN total END), 0) AS Italia,
  SUM(total) AS Total
FROM nombre_tabla
GROUP BY producto, marca;
```